# Is there any content unavailable after beating the final boss in Breath of the Wild?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Please keep the answer spoiler free if possible, I am curious how big the list of things to do before beating the final boss is if anything gets locked out after the final boss, or if the game reverts to a pre post game stage after beating the game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**. After defeating calamity ganon, your save gets marked with a star, but will otherwise be reverted to where it was before you defeated calamity ganon.

Comment: It might save weapon durability used in the fight, I don't know for sure

Comment: You also gain access to certain features after defeating ganon, so going for that star can be worth it

Comment: fyi it doens't save weapon durability used in the fight.  I've broken weapons in that fight but got them back after the ending.

Answer (score 0):

Your save reverts back to before the final battle (no, you don't get to keep the Bow of Light), except for one thing: any album pictures are saved. This means that you can get pictures of Calamity Ganon and Dark Beast Ganon naturally, as in without buying them from Purah.